# Given a linear function, how can I find the Ker?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the linear function

$f : (a, b, c, d, e) ∈ R^5 → (a − d, a − d, e − d, c) ∈ R^4$

How can I find the Ker?

Please help me.

Comment: Solve for $f(a,b,c,d,e)=(0,0,0,0)$

Comment: @Akababa What do you mean?

Comment: @Mark Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1):

Equal all the coordinates to zero...:

$$\begin{cases}a-d=0\\
a-d=0\\e-d=0\\c=0\end{cases}\;\;\implies a=d=e\;,\;\;c=0$$

so

$$\ker f=\left\{ (a,b,0,a,a)\;|\;a\in\Bbb R\right\}$$

Comment: Thank you! The exercise also asks me to find one of its basis and its
 dimension. How can I do?

Comment: For dimension: how many "free variables" does the set of elements in $\;\ker f\;$ have? And now choose that number of elements that will be linearly independent.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @Mark I believe you...but you'll have do to an extra effort. This is **very basic** stuff and you must try harder to understand it, so I'll leave it to you to re-read your notes or text book and make a serious effort to complete the answer.

Comment: One of its basis is $(0,1,0,0,0)$ and its dimension is $2$?

Comment: The dimension is correct, but then you need **two** elements in its basis. The vector you've given **indeed** belongs to $\;\ker f\;$ . Now you need *another one* that'll be linearly independent with this first one. Nice

Comment: I thought I had to find one basis. Well, the other one is $(1,0,0,1,1)$?

Comment: @Mark You really need to go again over the basic things, so do yourself a favour and re-read your notes/text book, otherwise you'll find much harder problems later. A basis for a linear space **has to have** as many elements as the space's dimension, so in your case "a basis" has to be a set with two elements. One single vector cannot possibly be a basis!

Comment: DonAntonio is completely right, if you miss basic concept you can’t learn all what follow by that, revise the concept of basis, it is a crucial point to understand linear algebra

Answer (score 0):

Given $f:R^n\to R^m $ note that $\ker f$ is defined as the set of all $x\in R^n$ such that $f(x)=0$, in this case we have

$$f(a, b, c, d, e)=(a − d, a − d, e − d, c)=0\implies\begin{cases}a-d=0\\a-d=0\\e-d=0\\c=0\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}a=d\\e=d\\c=0\end{cases}$$

thus set $d=t\in R$ and $b=s\in R$ we have

$$\ker f=\{(t,s,0,t,t)\in R^5 \quad t,s\in R\}$$

and $\ker f$ has dimension 2 since you have 2 free parameters and a basis is

$$v_1=(1,0,0,1,1) \quad v_2(0,1,0,0,0)$$

Comment: The above is wrong for two reasons: (1) because the basis is in $\;\Bbb R^5\;$ and not in $\;\Bbb R^4\;$ , so the elements you say are a basis ofr the kernel cannot possibly be. (2) You are trying to give the whole solution to the OP but, as you can see, he's struggling **and learning** trying to cope with my answer. Thus I'd say you check your answer to correct it and then just give hints or so for the OP to make an effort to understand this so basic stuff.

Comment: Sorry DonAntonio my intent was to help bur I’ve made a few of confusion, you are right I revise